# Use read line to iterate over variables

Tags: command-line, bash, ls

I have the following files:

```
$ ls *.png | egrep -i "am|pm"
output-0 11.42.30 AM.png
output-0 5.10.12 PM.png
....
```

I want to remove them but get this error:

```
$ ls *.png | egrep -i "am|pm" | while read line; do rm "$line"; done
rm: cannot remove ''$'\033''[0m'$'\033''[01;35moutput-0 11.42.30 AM.png'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ''$'\033''[01;35moutput-0 5.10.12 PM.png'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ''$'\033''[01;35moutput-1 11.42.30 AM.png'$'\033''[0m': No such file or directory
```

What's the problem with my codes?

Comment: I suspect `ls` is aliased to `ls --color=always` instead of `...=auto`. Try `\ls ...` to run the actual `ls` command and not some alias.

Comment: Please also see [Why *not* parse `ls` (and what do to instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/103151)

Comment: and [Bash pitfalls: `for f in $(ls *.mp3)`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29) and [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`ls` is risky in scripts and command lines. One problem is what is described in a comment by @PerlDuck, ANSI escape sequences for colour output. I would recommend another approach with `find`

- Create test files

  ```
  touch 'output-0 11.42.30 AM.png' 'output-0 5.10.12 PM.png' asdf.png
  ```
- Check that the `find`command line finds the files that you expect it to find

  ```
  find . -type f -iname "*[ap]m*.png"
  ```

  and do it

  ```
  find . -type f -iname "*[ap]m*.png" -delete
  ```

  If you don't want to search into subdirectories, add `-maxdepth 1`

  ```
  find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname "*[ap]m*.png" -delete
  ```
- Check the result

  ```
  ls
  ```

  Files with am, pm, AM, PM in the name should be deleted but `asdf.png` is not deleted.

Answer (score 6):

If you *really* want to use a `while read` loop in that way, then use a shell glob and `printf` with null delimiters e.g.

```
printf '%s\0' *.png | grep -zEi 'am|pm' | while IFS= read -r -d '' line; do echo "$line"; done
```

However, there are several ways to get `bash` to expand to a list of the files to be deleted directly - without the need to pipe to `grep` and `while`:

1. using simple shell globs

   ```
   rm -- *[ap]m.png *[AP]M.png
   ```

   or - if you don't mind matching a `.PNG` extension as well - making use of the `nocaseglob` option

   ```
   shopt -s nocaseglob
   rm -- *[ap]m.png
   ```
2. using *extended globs*

   ```
   shopt -s extglob
   rm -- *@(AM|PM).png *@(am|pm).png
   ```

or

```
    shopt -s extglob nocaseglob
    rm -- *@(am|pm).png
```

The `--` marks the end of options, just in case there are filenames that begin with a hyphen - you can use a pattern with an explicit directory prefix like `./*(am|pm)` instead if you prefer.

Add the `-i` or `-I` option if you want to review the file names interactively before deletion.