# Sort files by unpadded leading numbers

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have the following files

```
$ ls *.md | sort -n
1.pythonPrimer.md
10.mapsHashTablesAndSkipLists.md
11.searchTree.md
12.sortAndSelection.md
13.textProcessing.md
14.graphAlgorithms.md
15.memoryManagementAndBTrees.md
16.Appendix.md
2.Object Oriented Programming.md
3.algorithmsAnalysis.md
4.recursion.md
5.arrayBasedSequence.md
6.stack.md
7.linkedList.md
8.tree.md
9.priorityQueues.md
```

I want to sort them by the leading numbers in the order 1, 2, 3, 4....,

How could I get it done?

Comment: That should work exactly as you wrote it. Maybe your locale settings change the numeric sort order, or you have `ls` or `sort` aliased to something weird. Please [edit] to add the output of `locale` and `type -a ls sort`.

Answer (score 2):

It works for me too. I think it will work for you, if you define a key `-k` and  field separator `-t` for `sort`

```
ls *.md | sort -n -t. -k1
```

or with find

```
find * -name "*.md" | sort -n -t. -k1
```

---

You should avoid using `ls` like this in command lines. Things can go wrong for several reasons. See [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1097863/use-read-line-to-iterate-over-variables) (particularly the links in the comments by @Byte Commander).

Answer (score 1):

It works for me. Maybe you need to turn off locale?

```
ls *.md | LC_ALL=C sort -n
```

Or, use the version sorting in `ls`:

```
ls -v *.md
```